# "Blinds us to" or "blinds us from"?

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I see these phrases sometimes: 
"blinds us from" 
and 
"blinds us to". 
Which form is correct? The whole sentence would be something like "blinds us from the truth".

Comment: Both are used, but *to* may be the more common of the pair. Here are two OED citations employing *from*: OED citations follow: **1720** Ozell tr. Vertot’s *Rom. Rep.* II. ix. 92 ― A great Presumption blinded him from seeing his own Incapacity. ♢ **1821** Keats *Lamia* 373 ― Wherefore did you blind Yourself from his quick eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As tchrist suggests in a comment, "blind [one] from seeing" is more common than "blind [one] to seeing." Here is an Ngram chart of "blind me from seeing" vs. "blind me to seeing" vs. "blind us from seeing" vs. "blind us to seeing" vs. "blind them from seeing" vs. "blind them to seeing":

[image]

In situations where the thing that one is being blinded to or from is a simple noun (such as the truth), rather than a gerund-like action (such as seeing something), however, "blind [one] to" is far more common than "blind one from." Here is an Ngram chart of "blind me from" vs. "blind me to" vs. "blind us from" vs. "blind us to" vs. "blind them from" vs. "blind them to":

[image]

Note that this second Ngram chart includes the "blind [one] from [or to] [doing X]" results within the broader "blind [one] from [or to] [X]" results. In this view, the "blind [one] from" results very nearly flat-line, indicating a great overall predominance of the "blind [one] to" formulation despite the advantage that "blind [one] from" has in the case of phrases like "blind [one] from seeing."

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this figuratively, the action of blinding implies that what you are trying to access is something that "emits something" and *goes towards* you, such as as light. If you replace truth with "light", "blinds us from" is more natural.

Also, "from" implies that you are prevented from reaching something, or something is prevented from reaching you. "To" is more natural when used with an action that brings you closer to the noun. For example, "brings us to the truth".

Comment: You can be blinded from seeing the truth.

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved if instead of relying upon personal opinion alone, it had actual usage data from public corpora to back it up, such as the comparative frequency of the two variants via COCA or the BNC.